# Want to do something similar nytimes:Facebook offering in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, data-visualization

I want to do something similar to [NYTimes's facebook offering](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2012/05/17/business/dealbook/how-the-facebook-offering-compares.html) visualization.

I have a CSV file with this header: `Org,size,year`

All I want to do is to display a 2D chart `Org vs year` similar to the above  NYtimes visualization, with the node radius and opacity in function of my CSV's `size` column.

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fjmosf8k/) is an example

Comment: @JasonMartinez  I need my `Org`'s to be x axis and `year`'s to be y axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/fjmosf8k/9/) other example

```
function InitChart() {    
    var height = $("#svgVisualize").height();
    var width = $("#svgVisualize").width();

    var vis = d3.select("#svgVisualize");
    var xRange = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([100, width - 100])
        .domain([0, 11]);

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(label)
        .rangePoints([100, width - 100]);

    var yRange = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([400, 40])
        .domain([2006, 2015]);

    var alphaRange = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0.2, 1])
        .domain(
    [d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return (d.peso);
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.peso;
    })]);

    var radioRange = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([1, 20])
        .domain(
    [d3.min(data, function (d) {
        return (d.peso);
    }),
    d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return (d.peso);;
    })]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yRange)
        .tickFormat(d3.format("d"))
        .orient("left");

    /* Y AXIS */

    vis.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(100,0)");

    /* X AXIS */

    vis.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 400 + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-75)");

    /* CIRCLES */

    var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(data);

    circles.enter()
        .insert("circle")
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return xRange(d.x);
    })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return yRange(d.anio);
    })
        .attr("r", function (d) {
        return radioRange(d.peso);
    })
        .style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
        return alphaRange(d.peso)
    })
        .style("stroke", "#000")
        .style("fill", "#013E7F");
}
```

Comment: thanks!! how do I add hover? to the circles in order to show the size propertie?

Comment: You can use d3-tip, http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579